# Visually select to the middle of line

Tags: vim

I have this mapping that allows me to move to the middle of the line:

```
nnoremap <silent> M :execute 'normal! ' . (virtcol('$')/2) . '\|'<CR>
```

Can it be extended to work in visual mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems to work.

```
vnoremap <silent> M :<c-u>execute 'normal! gv' . (virtcol('$')/2) . '\|'<CR>
```

Since typing an ex command exits visual mode you need to first reselect the visual mode before  executing the `|` command.

`<c-u>` clears the command line which was prepopulated with `'<,'>`
`gv` reselects the old virtual selection.

vnoremap was used so that its a visual mode mapping.