# VSCode jump to the middle of current line

Tags: visual-studio-code, keyboard-shortcuts

There are many keyboard [shortcuts](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings) and [edit](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics) options in Visual Studio Code, I can move cursor: by character, by word, to beginning/end of line. But, if I'm editing a long line of text, how to faster jump to the middle of this line ?

Found similar question here, but for vim users - [Visually select to the middle of line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18435738/visually-select-to-the-middle-of-line)

Probably, it's possible to implement this option (jump to middle) with [Vim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) extension. If so, then how to do it ?

Is there a way to make such behaviour natively without any extensions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, this is built-in to vscode, using the `cursorMove` command.  Set up this keybinding in your `keybindings.json`:

```
{
  "key": "alt+c",
  "command": "cursorMove",
  "args": {
    "to": "wrappedLineColumnCenter",
    "select": true  // default is false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the extension [Select By](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.select-by) v1.0.0.

You can create a keybinding that calculates the new cursor position

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i ctrl+m",  // or any other key binding
    "when": "editorTextFocus",
    "command": "moveby.calculation",
    "args": {
      "charNrEx": "currentLine.length / 2"
    }
  }
```